# AWS Lambda :: How to test my code on my local ubuntu machine?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I have this Lambda function code which is invoked by an SQS. 
SQS triggers my Lambda function ( in nodeJS).

Lambda will also send out an SES email. Is there a way I can test this on my local Ubuntu rather than always using AWS web console?
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Lambda NodeJS code: This code works only on AWS Lambda. When I run 
$node index.js , it does not send out SES email.

```
    var aws = require("aws-sdk");
    var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

    aws.config.loadFromPath('aws_config.json');


    var ses = new aws.SES();
    var s3 = new aws.S3();

    // Set the region
    aws.config.update({region: 'us-west-2'});

    exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
            const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'SQS event processed.',
                input: event,
            }),
        };

        console.log('event: ', JSON.stringify(event.Records));
        result = JSON.stringify(event.Records)
        result = result.replace(/(^\[)/, '');
        result =  result.replace(/(\]$)/, '');    
        var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
        var idCustomer = resultObj.body;


        console.log('===SENDING EMAIL====');

    // Create sendEmail paramssd
    var params = {
        Destination: {
            /* required */
            CcAddresses: [
                'XXXXX@gmail.com',
                /* more items */
            ]
        },
        Message: {
            /* required s*/ 
            Body: {
                /* required */
                Html: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: "BODY:" 
                },
                Text: {
                    Charset: "UTF-8",
                    Data: "TEXT_FORMAT_BODY"
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Charset: 'UTF-8',
                Data: idCustomer
            }
        },
        Source: 'xxxx@eeeee.com', /* required */
        ReplyToAddresses: [
            'wwwwww@wwwwwwwww.com',
            /* more items */
        ],
    };

        // Create the promise and SES service object
        var sendPromise = new aws.SES({apiVersion: '2010-12-01'}).sendEmail(params).promise();

    // Handle promise's fulfilled/rejected states s
    sendPromise.then(
        function (data) {
            console.log("Successfully sent using SES");
            console.log(data.MessageId);
        }).catch(
        function (err) {
            console.log("An Error occured while senting using using SES");
            console.error(err, err.stack);
        });


    };
```

Comment: You can test lambda functions locally using [serverless](https://serverless.com/) with [serverless-offline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline), but it doesn't look like they have a local version of SES.

Comment: You need to configure AWS credential on the local machine. Create a user with full access to SES and use his credentials. You can use this reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definetely take a look at SAM LOCAL. It is a tool developed by the AWS team specifically for testing lambdas.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli

> Publishes a version of your function from the current snapshot of
>   $LATEST. That is, AWS Lambda takes a snapshot of the function code and
>   configuration information from $LATEST and publishes a new version.
>   The code and configuration cannot be modified after publication. For
>   information about the versioning feature, see

It is easy to use, you just type

```
sam local invoke --event event.json
```

And behind the scenes it will run a docker cotnainer for your lambda and call it.

Regarding your SES, you should put a small if(SAM_LOCAL) condition in the code and call the real one only if not in local mode. Note that SAM_LOCAL is env variable set by the SAM LOCAL tool when you run a function locally.

Good luck !

Comment: hi thanks very much for the answer. I installed SAM on my ubuntu.  In this command, sam local invoke --event event.json , can you give me the contents event.json ?

Comment: You can in theory put any valid json object. If your function is deployed behind an API gateway however you will need to have a special format like described in this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html

Comment: Thank you for the replies. 
Now I realised that I should use serverless platform to develop and deploy :) .  

I am now facing another error when trying to debug locally. It says ""     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.""  
Not sure where to set this. I have now got a serverless.yml which was created by 
"$serverless create -t aws-nodejs"

Comment: Do you know how many AWS services can  be executed on my local SAM?

Comment: If you have a template file that defines multiple lambdas with an API gateway you can do 'sam local start-api' which will bring up all your functions

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use aws as a backend - serverless framework is probably what you looking for https://serverless.com/ If you want to test your code without executing lambda on aws backend take a look at localastack framework  https://github.com/localstack/localstack

Comment: How do most people develope Lambda? Do they use AWS web console?  or do they use serverless? I just wanted to know how everyone does it. I find developing on the normal AWS web console is easy for testing etc. Only thing is I dont know how to manager my code / version the lambda.

Comment: Serverless framework works really well for developing production aws lambda based projects.

Comment: I like serverless too. If you have experience with SLS, can you please give the an example of "SQS triggering Lambda" development and deployment using sls? I was stuck with deploying to different environments ( staging and prod) and also environmental variables, and simulating SQS triggering of Lambda